# Inserting row number in the table while appending new row

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to append new row in my table with row number but this is not working.

```
$('.dropdown-menu li a:eq(8)').on('click', function(){
     rows='';     
     var myRow =(this).rowIndex;
     var row='<tr><td>'+myRow+'</td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td></tr>';
     rows=rows+row;
     $(rows).appendTo('table');


});
```

It is returning undefind in place of row number.

Comment: post your html codes too

Comment: no need.everything is fine bt check variable myRow.

Comment: yes that is we need to see your `<table>` codes atleast

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
$('.dropdown-menu li a:eq(8)').on('click', function(){  
     var rows='<tr><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td></tr>';
     $(rows).appendTo('table');
     $('table tr:last td:first-child').text(parseInt($('table tr').length)-1); // Minus 1 because index starts from 0.
});
```

Comment: lendth? Never heard about it. Did you try it?